# COM application loads the cryptbase.dll from the local application folder instead of system32

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I have developed an COM application in VC++ using visual studio 2012, when I launch the application it is looking for the cryptbase.dll in the local application folder instead of the system32 folder.

How can make the application to load the cryptbase.DLL from system32 folder.

Or any idea why ole32!CoInitializeEx call loads cryptbase.dll to the process space.

Comment: "using visual studio 2012" - why? VS2017 is better in every way. Why stay stuck in the past?

Comment: It might be registered in the application folder.  Is the dll in the system32 folder?  If so, it must not be properly registered to that location.

Comment: ole32.dll just has a lot of dependencies, it does a lot.  Maybe you ought to check that your PATH environment variable is still correct, too many wonky installers corrupt it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl : I tried with VS2015, even same behavior. I didn't tried with VS 2017.

Comment: @ttemple : cryptbase.dll is not a COM DLL, it is microsoft non COM DLL available in the system 32 folder. my application is loading the fake dll named cryptbase.dll available in the local application folder instead of the one in the system 32 folder.

Comment: @HansPassant : I checked the PATH var, it doesn't have the local application path, still it is loading from the local application folder.

Comment: @Basu I didn't suggest a newer compiler thinking you'd get a different result (in this case). I merely suggested it since there is no reason to get stuck with an old tool-chain.

Comment: Why does it actually matter that it looks in the app folder?  It doesn't have a copy of cryptbase.dll there does it?   You'll have to get rid of that.  Search order is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks for the search order Link.
I think it will help me to fix this issue. but any idea why ole32!CoInitializeEx call loads cryptbase.dll to the process space.

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Thank you all for the support, I could fix this by calling the "SetDefaultDllDirectories" in the starting of the application. thanks @HansPassant for sharing the  Search order link.