# DLL Hijack/Preloading issue in WPF application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, winapp

I have created wpf application using visual studio 2019(.Net Framework 4.7.2). Builded it.
In bin/debug folder I have placed one dll(cryptbase.dll) which is having a simple message box.
When ever I am running my exe of wpf application from debug folder first its executing cryptbase.dll and showing message box and main application is not launching at all.

This is a simple demonstration of my problem.
I have tried mutiple ways to fix this dll hijacking issue.
Can some please suggest some approach so that it should run my application first.

I have tried to change dll search order also, but that code is not getting hit and dll is getting executing before reaching there.

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    private const int LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS = 0x00000800;


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetDefaultDllDirectories(int directoryFlags);

    public App()
    {
        if (!SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to exclude application directory from DLL directories, error code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please let me know if there is any fix for this?

Comment: That's not DLL hijacking at all. DLLs are loaded in a specific order and the application's folder is at the top of the list. That's documented in [Dynamic-link library search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN). There's an identical C++ question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632982/com-application-loads-the-cryptbase-dll-from-the-local-application-folder-instea).

Comment: What you did was intentionally break the deployment by making a copy of a system DLL in the local folder. This wouldn't happen in a realistic scenario, where applications are deployed in `Program Files`. That folder is read-only specifically to prevent careless users or applications from breaking installations by overwriting executables. To get `cryptbase.dll` in there you'd have to intentionally include it in your installer. Which is no different than just showing the message box in your own code.

Comment: If you use MSI/MSIX to install the application, the OS itself will check that all files are OK when you start the app and repair it if they aren't. BTW the application starts at the compiler-generated Main function, not the `App` constructor. By the time `App` is created, the entire process is up and running. If you set the search path to only System32 though, you may not be able to load your own application's assemblies

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually we are not creating the installer,  We have to do it by packaging The build from release mode, As we have to add some more supporting file which are unique for every client. 
Hacker can execute any code from cryptbase.dll.

Comment: No you don't have to. No, only the actual end user can add extra files and only after passing through the UAC dialog box. And even then, Windows may well redirect any writes to another shadow folder. Too many lazy developers tried to force writes to `Program Files`, breaking their own and others' applications. Don't try to reinvent the features built to avoid problems like this. If you don't understand how things work you'll only end up harming people and your own company